# Best practices for implementing an iOS download manager with progress view

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, progress

I have a UITableViewController displaying a list of audio files, when tapping on an audio file I push another UITableViewController showing a detailed view of the audio file. This view also features a "Download" button and a UIProgressIndicator view.

I have a Download Manager class (implemented as a Singleton) which takes care of downloading the file. Its download method takes a block which is called with updates about the download progress. I'm using it to update the UIProgressIndicator view. This works fine up to the point where you leave the detail view controller and come back at a later point in time when the file is still downloading. Of course, the progress block specified earlier is still available, but the referenced UIProgressIndicator view inside of it is not, thus it is not updated anymore.

I'm wondering, if it's a sensible idea to just re-set the block upon re-entering the detail view controller (viewDidLoad) or if the block-based approach is not really suitable for this case? Maybe it'd be better to use KVO?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block approach is useful if the lifespan of the downloader is controlled by the VC. This way, when the VC is released, it releases the downloader (the downloader would not be a singleton).
If not you risk creating captured objects (the VC) that cannot be released because they are referenced in your block, and your block is referenced by an "eternal" object (the singleton).

As the VC lifespan is potentially shorter than the downloader, a better option would be to use some subscription-based observing of the downloader singleton.

This way your VC subscribes in (e.g.) viewWillAppear and *unsubscribes* in viewWillDisappear (important).

You can also use a global progress notification (via NSNotificationCenter), key-value observing or any other means.

The important part is that when your VC is released, nothing in the downloader points to it.

Comment: Yeah, the lifetime of the VC is the most important part. I often solved this via NSNotifications send by the downloader-code. Its performant and easy to implement and gives a loosely coupled system.

Comment: Also, if you want to use KVO+blocks, check Block-KVO https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Block-KVO

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I went with the KVO approach and it made the code so much easier to understand and less error-prone ... once I figured out that observeValueForKeyPath isn't necessarily executed on the main thread and I had to throw in dispatch_async to avoid crashes when updating the progress indicator view.